# How to insert a very large number of records into a MySql database as fast as possible

Tags: .net, mysql, connector-net

I have a database table like below:

```
create table temperature
(id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
temperature double
);
```

And in my program I got about 20 million temperature to insert into the table.
I worke in .Net environment, use Connector/Net connecting to MySql. The code was like below:

```
List<double> temps = new List<double>();
...
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=name;database=test;port=3306;password=*****;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
try
{
    conn.Open();

    //temps.Count is about 20 million
    for (int i = 0; i < temps.Count; i++)
    {
        string sql1 = "INSERT INTO temperature VALUES (null, "+temps[i]+")";
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sql1, conn);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
conn.Close();
```

How can i insert so many lines data as fast as possible?
(It can only insert 2000 records every minute in my computer.)

Comment: I'm a bit curious. Why would you insert 20 millions temperatures in a DB ?

Comment: Do you need autoincrement? I have a similar situation (on sql server) and I manage the increment keys client side on the loader. I mange 75.000 rows per second on my current hardware. No SQL, though...

Comment: Also your sql "sucks" ;) can you not submit multiple insert statements in one run? It is a string - can mysql handle hthat? 10 isnerts per round trip is 10% the round trips. THreads add moer to that (multi threaded load).

Comment: @TomTom I strongly believe that multithreaded 'forcing' of data into the server won't help a lot here, since it would generate unnecessary locking at the server.

Comment: Oh, but - most of the time the server does nto do anything here because you ahve round trips from client to server. Send data, wait for data back - in this time another thread could updaet the table.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways to optimize bulk inserts. Some are:

- `LOAD DATA INFILE`. There is a [wrapper API for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html). This is the fastest way, but has some limitations and semantic differences from simple inserts.
- Multiple-row `INSERT` statements:

  `INSERT INTO temperature (temperature) VALUES (1.0), (2.0), (3.0), ...`

  You should not insert 20.000.000 rows at once, but may want to try 1.000-10.000 for a very large speed-up. This is a simple and very unproblematic way to increase speed. A factor of 10 and sometimes way more is often possible.
- Locking the table (`LOCK TABLES`).
- Disabling indexes temporarily.
- MySQL options tuning.
- `INSERT DELAYED` (most likely not that useful here).

The documentation does give you [more elaborate detail](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html) on the options. Some options depend on the table type ([InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) vs. [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html)).

A general suggestion: Always specify the columns that you insert in front of `VALUES`. This makes for more maintainable code.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the concept of `bulk insert` which executes many inserts at the same time minimizing overhead of calling `ExecuteNonQuery` multiple times.

in MySQL this is called `LOAD DATA`, check here for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

in MS SQL Server this is called `bulk insert` and it's known as such, that's why I've mentioned it with this name.

Answer (score 2):

General rules :-

1. [use load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
2. disable key during import, enable it back after all data has been import
3. run the script at the database server itself, connect using socket instead of tcp/ip

Most of the tips are explained at the documentation.

Comment: general rule #2 won't apply here, since it is autonumber primary key

Answer (score 2):

You should do bulk inserts. The ADO.NET way to do it is by using a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx).

For a MySQL specific solution, use the [MySqlBulkLoader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html).