# Quickest way to Insert mass data Into Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I actually have a list of 100,000 records which I'd like to insert into the MySQL database.

I have tried to insert them with `foreach` and simple `INSERT INTO` however it took a lot of time to insert even 100 row. Like 1 second / row.

IS there any method to insert these rows much faster?

Comment: Can you do a data import using a tool like phpMyAdmin or the MySQL command line interface or a similar tool (e.g. Toad)?

Comment: Actually I'd like to add this 100,000 list to an existing list. So importing wouldn't be okay :/

Comment: An import would allow you to do the inserts even with a table containing pre-existing records.  Clone your table structure and some records (if a very large table) and experiment a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert 20 million record into MySQL database as fast as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8474926/608639).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using one INSERT statement with multiple rows is faster than one INSERT statement per row.
This will reduce calls to the database.

Example:

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 5):

Make packages:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(`column`) VALUES('value'),VALUES('value1'),VALUES('value2'), ..., VALUES('valuen');
```

[documentation for insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

or export data to csv or other text format and use `LOAD DATA`, look here: [load data by mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

fastest way to load large dataset is to use bulk loading interface.
Refer Mysql docs: [Bulk loader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to use command line interface. You can use mysqldump util.

Answer (score 0):

Group several similar INSERTs in one long INSERT with multiple VALUES lists to insert several rows at a time: query will be quicker due to fact that connection + sending + parsing a query takes 5-7 times of actual data insertion (depending on row size). If that is not possible, use START TRANSACTION and COMMIT, if your database is InnoDB, otherwise use LOCK TABLES — this benefits performance because the index buffer is flushed to disk only once, after all INSERT statements have completed; in this case unlock your tables each 1000 rows or so to allow other threads access to the table.

From this article: http://www.ajaxline.com/node/2099

Answer (score -1):

(only for mysql)

update: you can use mysql_random_data_load
plugin to make it

[github link click here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/Percona-Lab/mysql_random_data_load&ved=2ahUKEwjeoL-9levwAhWQad4KHV70BroQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw2ZmF4DzxpNZK2McNms4MV1)

---

**This makes a function to return random names. you can change it to fit yourself**

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_name`() RETURNS varchar(5) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE chars varchar(255) default '里对非肺乔额及爱我动物地位三次幂动物';
    DECLARE str varchar(255) default '';
    DECLARE i int default 0;
    while i<3 do
        set str=concat(str,substring(chars, FLOOR(1 + RAND()*62), 1));
        set i=i+1;
    END while;
RETURN str;
END
```

**make a procedure to achieve making lots of data**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `make_data`(size int)
BEGIN
    declare i int default 0;
    while i<size do
        insert table_name(name)value(get_name());
    end while;
END
```

**call make_data(1000)[done]**

> If you use MySQL Workbench, you need to add function and procedure manually.
> If you use MySQL console, then you should add DELIMITER like below

```
DELIMITER $$
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `make_data`(size int)
BEGIN
    declare i int default 0;
    while i<size+1 do
        insert table_name(name)value(get_name());
    end while;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```