# Insert 60000 rows Mysql from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with a backend: PHP.

In one table I have to insert **60,000 rows**.

We made a query into my PHP that returns 1,000 rows. For each rows we have to insert 60 rows. We thought **make a loop** but we don't know if is the best practices that way.

The part of the code that insert the data is:

```
$turnos = $db->query("SELECT * FROM turno t 
                    WHERE t.canchaId = :cancha 
                    AND t.fecha BETWEEN :fechaInicio AND :fechaFin
                    AND t.nombre LIKE :cadena
                    ORDER BY t.fecha,t.hora ASC",
            array("cancha" => $cancha["idCancha"], "fechaInicio" => $fechaInicio, "fechaFin" => $fechaFin, "cadena" => "%turno fijo%"));
foreach($turnos as $turno) {
    //turnos have 1000 rows
    $fecha = date_create($turno["fecha"]);
    date_add($fecha, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
    $anioAuxiliar = 2017;

    while(2017 == $anioAuxiliar){
        //60 times
        $data1 = turno[data1]; 
        $data2 = turno[data2];
        ...
        $fechaAGuardar = (String) $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
        $result = $db->query("INSERT INTO turno(fechaAGuardar, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8)   VALUES(:fechaAGuardar, :data2, :data3, :data4, :data5, :data6, :data7, :data8)",
        array("fechaAGuardar" => $fechaAGuardar, "data2" => $data2, "data3" => $data3, "data4" => $data4, "data5" => $data5, "data6" => $data6, "data7" => $data7, "data8" => $data8));

        date_add($fecha, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
        $anioAuxiliar = (int) $fecha->format("Y");
    }

    $cantidad_turnos = $cantidad_turnos + 1;
}
```

This php is into a hosting with phpmyadmin.

So my questions are:

**This is the best way to insert 60,000 rows?**

**Shall we considerer take into account another constraint? (eg: phpmyadmin don't allow you insert that amount of rows)**

Thanks for helping me, Any suggestions are welcome

**//EDIT//**

The inserts data change, we have to insert datetime, and for each loop we have to add 7 day the last date inserted. So we can't use insert with select

Comment: Batch insert is the best way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickest way to Insert mass data Into Mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474675/quickest-way-to-insert-mass-data-into-mysql-database)

Comment: Please, can give us an example? We don't know how to make a bath file with mysql. Other recommend us using batch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT with SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

Comment: the other post not using loop

Comment: @MonkeyZeus , we have to insert data into a loop, and also we have to change the values, eg: we insert datetime, so for each loop we have to insert datetime + 7 days. is dynamically data.

Comment: NOTE: **`phpMyAdmin`** is a tool written in PHP IT IS NOT the database. MYSQL is the database

Comment: Surely this is a ONE-OFF script. Worrying about if it is done in the best way is therefore unnecessary. _If it works use it then throw it away_

Comment: @FederickJons MySQL is perfectly capable of performing the dynamic calculations which you've described.

Comment: Please show the `SELECT` query which provides the data for `$turnos`

Comment: btw: typehinting does not work for primitive types
`$anioAuxiliar = (int) $fecha->format("Y");`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've just edited the post with  the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a bunch of fellows described in the comments, INSERT/SELECT is the way to go if this data is in the same server/database. There's no need to use PHP at all. Your year comment can be [handled with DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Anyway, if there is any other requirement and you can't use PHP, consider using [Bulk Data Loading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).

Analysing your code, the **MOST IMPORTANT TIP** would be: don't use multiple `INSERT INTO TABLE` expressions. Each INSERT INTO will cause a round trip do the database and things will get really slow. Instead of it, concat multiple values with one `INSERT INTO` (example from the link):

> INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (1,2), (5,5), ...;

Good luck!